# why does the camera have to stay at the origin in opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, render

So i'm learning openGL and one thing I find very strange is that the camera has the stay at the origin and look in the same direction. To achieve camera movement and rotation you have to move and rotate the entire world instead of the camera.

My question is, why can't you move the camera? Does directx allow you to move the camera?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I think the answer depends on what you actually mean, when you are talking about a fixed camera.

As a matter of fact instead of saying openGL has a fixed camera I'd rather tend to say there isn't any camera at all in openGL.

On the other hand I wouldn't agree with your interpretation that the openGL API moves or rotates the world.

Instead I'd say the openGL API doesn't move or rotate the world at all.

I think the reason why there isn't any concept of a camera in the openGL API is, because it isn't meant as a high level abstraction layer, but rather linked to the computational necesissities in displaying computer graphics.

As I suggest you're mainly talking about displaying 3-dimensional scenes this means transforming 3D vertex data to a 2D raster image.

For every frame rendered this involves transforms transforming the 3-D coordinates of every vertex in your scene to their corresponding 2D location on the screen.

As every vertex has to be placed at the right position on screen it doesn't make any computational difference at all if you conceptually move something like a camera around or just move the whole world, you'll have to do the same transformation nonetheless.

The mathmatics involved in computing the "right" position for a vertex on screen can be described by a mathmatical object called matrix that, when applied (the mathmatical term used for this application is matrix-multiplication) to 3-D data will result in the desired 2D screen coordinates.

So essentially what happens in rendering a 3-D scene - regardless of the fact if there is any camera at all or not - is that every vertex is processed by some transformation matrix, leaving the original 3-D data of your vertex intact.

As the 3-D vertex data doesn't get changed at all, I'd say the openGL doesn't move or rotate the world at all, but this "observation" may depend on the observers perspective.

As a matter of fact leaving the 3-D vertex data intact without changing it all is essential to prevent your 3-D scene from deforming due to accumulated rounding inaccuracy.

I hope I could help by expressing my opinon on who or what moves whom when or why in the openGL API.

Even if I couldn't convice you there is no word-moving involved in using the openGL API don't forget the fact it doesn't weight anything at all so moving it around shouldn't be too painful.

BTW. don't bother to investigate about the proprietary library mentioned in your question and keep relying on open standards.

Answer (score 2):

What's the difference between moving the world and moving the camera? Mathematically... there isn't any; it's the same number either way. It's all a matter of perspective. As long as you code your camera abstraction correctly, you don't have to think of it as moving the world if you don't want to.